# How can I find the complexity of this recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I've to solve the following recurrence:

$T(n) = 2T(n-1) - 1$, for $n \geq 1$

$T(n) = 1$, for $n = 0$

I'd easily proved that $T(n) = O(2^n)$, however it seems that $T(n)$ is $O(1)$ actually.

So, how can I prove it? Any ideas?

Comment: Well... let's see.  $T(0)=1$.  $T(1)=2T(0)-1=2-1=1$ so $T(1)=1$ as well.  It should be trivial then to show that $T(n)=1$ for all $n$ from this.  Note that this comes as a result of the chosen initial condition.  If $T(0)$ were anything else, for example $2$, then the sequence wouldn't have been constant.

Comment: I can see that it always get to 1, independently the value of n. But I saw this as a "tree of recursions", that means that every node $i$ always calls 2 times $T(i-1)$. That's why the $2^n$.

Comment: Yes... In general a recurrence of the form $T(n)=kT(n-1)-1$ with $k\neq 1$ will have closed form $T(n)=c_1\cdot k^n + c_2$ for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ which depend on the initial conditions.  It so happens that for your specific problem with the initial condition of $T(0)=1$ that this will imply that $c_1=0$.

Comment: Note that $O(1)$ is $O(2^n)$ (i.e., constants grow no faster than exponentials), so yes, $T(n) \in O(2^n)$. But by narrowing your focus to look at only one aspect of the problem to the exclusion of all else, you failed to notice that a much tighter bound could be accomplished.